# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

This code is supposed to return the total cost for a trip to different cities

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140*nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = days*40
    if days>=7:
        cost = cost - 50
    elif days>=3:
        cost = cost - 20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)+plane_ride_cost(city)+spending_money

print trip_cost("Los_Angeles",5,600)
```

It is running fine if i dont call the function `plane_ride_cost` but if I do it is showing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 25, in <module>
File "python", line 23, in trip_cost
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: You don't have a `Los_Angeles` city in `plane_ride_cost`.

Comment: @Sairam: Please take a look at the other questions on SO - and please reword your question to be specific.

Comment: Without a traceback I'm just guessing that one of those in the `return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)+plane_ride_cost(city)+spending_money` is none

Comment: `"Los_Angeles" != "Los Angeles"`. `plane_ride_cost` should `raise` an error (or *maybe* `return` a sensible, numerical default default) in cases where the location isn't known.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Use `print trip_cost("Los Angeles",5,600)` instead of `print trip_cost("Los_Angeles",5,600)`

Comment: Please keep in mind the Stack Overflow community is made of human beings. You should talk to us and explain your problem with actual words, not just dump the error message and your code like if we were mindless web services.

Comment: i am sorry about that i am new to the community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo

```
"Los_Angeles" != "Los Angeles"
```

But more importantly you don't have an `else` case to handle the situation where they enter a city that is not in your list